# CloudKit - How to retrieve the ckRecordID of the record just saved using CKModifyRecordsOperation

Tags: cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

I'm using CoreData for keeping a local cache of records in CloudKit. When saving a new record, I do the following:

1. Insert record to CoreData. I flag this record as not updated in CloudKit. Just in case my CKModifyRecordsOperation fails, I can still update it at a later time to CloudKit using this flag.
2. Insert record to CloudKit using CKModifyRecordsOperation.
3. Try fetching the ckRecordID of the record inserted in step #2. (That's where my logic fails as I'm not sure how I can achieve this). I do not have any other keys (reference) and wish to use only CKRecordID as a reference between CoreData and CloudKit.
4. Update the ckRecordID (fetched in step #3) to CoreData.

What would be the best logic to solve the above? Thank you for your time and responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by creating a CKRecordID locally and updating it in CloudKit. Below is the quote from apple documentation:

> To assign a custom record ID to a new record, you must create the
>   CKRecordID object first. You need to know the intended name and zone
>   information for that record, which might also require creating a
>   CKRecordZone.ID object. After creating the record ID object,
>   initialize your new record using its init(__recordType:recordID:)
>   method.

Here's my code:

```
let zone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: Schema.Zone.group)
let uuid = NSUUID()
let recordType = Schema.RecordType.group
let recordName = uuid.uuidString
let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: recordName, zoneID: zone.zoneID)
let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: recordID)
```